# Query for getting values not present in one table while comparing from another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables. 1st contains a list of all students with their ID, fname and lastname. 2nd has their ID, date and attendance.

Which query can I use to compare the date and id from 2nd table to the 1st table to see from the list of all students that who were absent on that particular day.

I thought of using outer joins but not really sure how that works. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add some sample data.

Comment: t1 left join t2 ... where t2.c is null...

Comment: 2nd table has records for all the students for a particular day or just the student who were present? If later, then what is the significance of attendance column? Without any sample data, we can only assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM students
LEFT JOIN attendances ON students.id=attendances.student_id
WHERE attendances.attendance = true AND attendances.date='neededDate';
```

I suppose your two tables are students and attendances, the attendances table has student_id as a foreign key and attendance field is boolean. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The below query has been written with the below assumpations
The column attendance contains NULL values if student was not present and other value if he/she was present

```
SELECT 
a.id,
concat(a.fname||' '||a.lname) As Full_Name,
b.date,
case when b.attendance is Null 'Absent' else 'Present' End as Attendance_Status
FROM students a
LEFT JOIN attendances b ON students.id=b.student_id
b.date='&RequiedDate';
```

The Required Date will be taken as an input parameter from the user